# How do I filter by attribute and value across multiple elements?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

I'm trying to find a XML node by checking it's type (type is an attribute). I can do this successfully with the following code:

```
var xml:XML = describeType(this);
var classname:String = getQualifiedClassName(mainGroup);
var xmlList:XMLList = xml.accessor.(@type==classname);
if (xmlList.length()) {
    trace("Found:" + xmlList[0]);
}
```

But I do not know if it will always be an "accessor" element. It could be an "variable" element or possibly something else. So I want to search all elements in the XML that have a type attribute that has a value that matches the value I'm looking for. When I use the following it says it's invalid:

```
// 1084: Syntax error: expecting doublecolon before semicolon.
var xmlList:XMLList = xml..(@type==classname);
```

What is the correct syntax to get the information I'm looking for?

Here is some XML to test with:

```
<type name="MyApplication" base="spark.components::WindowedApplication" isDynamic="false" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
    <accessor name="explicitMinWidth" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="mx.core::UIComponent"/>

    <accessor name="mainGroup" access="readwrite" type="components::MainGroup" declaredBy="MyApplication">

    </accessor>

    <variable name="controlBarGroup" type="spark.components::Group">

    </variable>
</type>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the `*` like this :

```
var xml:XML = <type name="MyApplication" base="spark.components::WindowedApplication" isDynamic="false" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
    <accessor name="explicitMinWidth" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="mx.core::UIComponent" />
    <accessor name="mainGroup" access="readwrite" type="components::MainGroup" declaredBy="MyApplication" />
    <variable name="controlBarGroup" type="spark.components::Group" />
    <variable name="explicitMinWidth" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="mx.core::UIComponent" />
</type>;

var xml_list:XMLList = xml.*.(@type == 'Number');
trace(xml_list.length());   // gives : 2
```

**EDIT :**

To avoid the error `Error #1065: Variable type is not defined` and drop lines which didn't contain the `type` attribut, you can use :

```
var xml_list:XMLList = xml.*.(attribute('type') == 'Number');
trace(xml_list.length());   // gives : 2
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Do you mean that your xml data didn't contain a "type" attribut ?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Yes exactly, I was just editing my answer when I saw your comment ;)